# Wordpress Search by tags

Tags: search, tags

How can I set by using functions.php, Wordpress search that the searching be only by tags.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can install WordPress Extended Search

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-extended-search/

It adds a settings page to the basic WordPress settings. From there you can turn off everything apart from searching by tags.